# Выдает ошибку cannot add foreign key constraint

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin

```
CREATE TABLE order1 
( order_id int not null AUTO_INCREMENT,
 date date not null,
 status varchar(25) not null,
 price int,
 exp_price int,
 employee_id int not null,
 service_id int not null,
 customer_id int not null,
 CONSTRAINT pk_order1 PRIMARY KEY (order_id),
 FOREIGN KEY (employee_id) REFERENCES employee(employee_id),
 FOREIGN KEY (service_id) REFERENCES service(service_id),
 FOREIGN KEY (customer_id) REFERENCES customer(customer_id)
 );`
`
```

Answer (score 1):

CONSTRAINT используются для указания правил для данных в таблице, для ограничения типа данных, которые могут попадать в таблицу.

В этой строке 
CONSTRAINT pk_order1 PRIMARY KEY (order_id)
Вы пытаетесь использовать CONSTRAINT для pk_order1, который не относится к данной таблице. Это является причиной ошибки.